# Automated Deployment with svn,ssh and plsql

Tags: svn, deployment, ssh, automation

the process which we are following now is:

1.developer sends the path of the code in the mail(svn path).
2.we do check for modifications in the source code folder and copy the modified files to my local machine.
3.run the backend components(.sql,.pck,.prg) in pl-sql developer.
4.transfer the frontend components to specified paths in remote server through ssh.
5.Take the logs of steps 3&4 and mail to developer.

Is there a way to automate the whole process.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest the following. Sending Files via Mail and compiling is very very primitive. You can use Hudson or Jenkins to automate this. When Hudson runs, it will update the modified or added files to its working directory. In case of Backend compilations, first you need to export the files to some temporary location. From their you can use ANT to compile the backend files in the schema. For front end files transfer to application server, you can use the "execute shell" or deployment options available with Hudson/Jenkins.

You can use something like [this](http://www.electrictoolbox.com/subversion-export-changed-files-cli/) to export the modified files since the last build. But you need to keep the last build svn revision, somewhere, may be in a text file for the next build to export the incremental files to a temporary location.

For backend compilation you can use, ANT.

[image]